# I want to create a random number, store the digits of the random number into an array, then store the array into a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

I want to create a random number, store the digits of the random number into an array, then store the array into a string. I am trying to hide the digits from the user. This is what I have, it is only storing two numbers. How can I fix this or do it differently so it works?

```
int random, n, digit;
            

srand(time(NULL));

        random = (rand() % 9999)+1000;

        n= random;

        char a[11];
        int i = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
        long int digit = n % 10;
        a[i] = digit;
        ++i;
        n /= 10;
        }
        a[i] = '\0';

        

        cout << digit << endl;

        string hiddenNumber(to_string(digit).length(),'-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for just suggestion, as I see no others. One can prevent fields from being spied upon, as the open source, certified and been around almost as long as me. I don't know the technique, but if that's something that fits part of your needs, the code is certainly available to learn from.. assuming you want a high security implementation. Other programs do it too of course, that one's just been around a long time so comes to mind first.
Uncertain how well the security of the field translates from the original windows to everything else it's been ported to, so keep an eye there.
Hope that's part of what you're looking for. Cheers. Official is:
https://keepass.info/
There's other download sites, but I'd stick with official just to be safe.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood, but how is your reply any way related to the question?

Answer (score -1):

The logical error in the above approach is that the digits will be stored in reverse order in the array. If your final outcome is just to get a string form of a random number, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n =  (rand() % 9999)+1000;
    char str[256];
    sprintf(str, "%d", n);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```